# Mono Boehm vs SGen GC

Tags: ios, mono, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have an application developed (renamed in my error as MyApplication for privacy) on the following enviroment:

- Monotouch 2.1
- MonoDevelop 2.4.2
- MacOS 10.6.8
- iOS SDK 4.3

that work fine.

Now i'm try to migrate to iOS 5.0/5.1 and Monotouch 5.2.5 with MonoDevelop 2.8.8.4.
My application crashes immediately with the following error:

> Stacktrace:

```
at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0009f, 0xffffffff>
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00042] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:29
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:34
  at MyApplication.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/MyPC/Projects/Test/MyApplication/Main.cs:19
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>
```

Native stacktrace:

```
0   MyApplication                            0x000908fc mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 284
1   MyApplication                            0x00005c98 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 248
2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9138145b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02958753 prepareForMethodLookup + 93
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0294f069 lookUpMethod + 86
6   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0294f1d6 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache + 40
7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x029620e3 objc_msgSend + 87
8   UIKit                               0x01cba799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
9   UIKit                               0x01cbcc2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
10  UIKit                               0x01cbba1c -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 277
11  UIKit                               0x01c4ed41 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 395
12  UIKit                               0x01c2fc37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
13  UIKit                               0x01c34f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
14  GraphicsServices                    0x03fa5992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00df8944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d58cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d55f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00d55840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00d55761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
20  GraphicsServices                    0x03fa41c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
21  GraphicsServices                    0x03fa4289 GSEventRun + 115
22  UIKit                               0x01c38c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
23  ???                                 0x090a61fc 0x0 + 151675388
24  ???                                 0x090a60c8 0x0 + 151675080
25  ???                                 0x090a59c0 0x0 + 151673280
26  ???                                 0x090a590c 0x0 + 151673100
27  ???                                 0x090a5997 0x0 + 151673239
28  MyApplication                            0x0000a002 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 722
29  MyApplication                            0x00169efe mono_runtime_invoke + 126
30  MyApplication                            0x0016dfe4 mono_runtime_exec_main + 420
31  MyApplication                            0x00173405 mono_runtime_run_main + 725
32  MyApplication                            0x00067205 mono_jit_exec + 149
33  MyApplication                            0x002116d5 main + 2837
34  MyApplication                            0x00003055 start + 53
35  ???                                 0x00000004 0x0 + 4
```

> Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates a
>   fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used
>   by your application.

It is the same if i deploy it to iOS SDK 4.3. I'm thinking it might be a problem with the new GC SGen as mentioned here http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/02/MonoTouch-SGen

UPDATE: In fact error is showed on a Alert show as lv.Message = "Copy...";

> Class Handle: the requested operation cannot be completed because the
>   object has been garbage collected

How could i solve it?

Comment: Report the bug to Mono team: http://www.mono-project.com/Bugs

Comment: I'm waiting to have an account...maybe in max 3 days it's done...

Comment: The **sgen** garbage collector is not enabled by default in MonoTouch 4.x (it's not default in 5.x either). Use https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ to report bugs. Account creation should be very fast.

Comment: I reported the bug about monodevelop and I was told I would have answered on StackOverflow. In fact Rolf Bjarne Kvinge belongs to Mono Team and he answered in the way you see...but for me it's not a best programming practice. What you think?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In MonoTouch 4 the GC is executed more aggressively to catch as early as possible a certain type of programming errors: ensuring that native objects aren't freed to early by the GC.

The most common pattern is to declare variables in a method:

```
void Method ()
{
    var view = new UIView ();
    otherNativeObject.NativeProperty = view;
}
```

What happens here is that the managed GC does not see that the otherNativeObject has a reference to the view, so when the method finishes executing, the GC will free the view. At a later point otherNativeObject will try to use the view, and you will end up with a crash similar to the one you reported (the exact stack trace and messages will vary a bit depending on where the freed native object is accessed).

The fix for the above example is easy, just make the view a class variable:

```
UIView view;
void Method ()
{
    view = new UIView ();
    otherNativeObject.NativeProperty = view;
}
```

now the GC will not be able to free the view when the method exits.

Note that this crash isn't new in MonoTouch 4, the effect of making the GC more aggressive is that you'll see the problem when debugging, as opposed to hearing it from your clients when they (very randomly) crash.

Comment: According to you this is a best programming practice?!

Comment: It is a side-effect of having two types of memory managed in the same process (refcounting in ObjectiveC and garbage collection in C#). The garbage collector cannot know everything about the ObjectiveC code (and thus cannot look at the ObjectiveC code to determine if an object is collectible or not) - the garbage collector needs a little bit of help from you.

Comment: This is a good answer...does not help me but I understood what problem has monodevelop with XCode interactions. It's good that now we can recognize previously problems that would have been unknown, disadvantage is the inability to use implicit references...this happens with all types or only with the UIView? Is there any good programming practice that you recommended to use?

Comment: It happens with all types derived from NSObject. The recommended practice is to use class-level variables for all objects derived from NSObject as opposed to method variables (whenever you store that object in a native property of course).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. Will there be any future developments on this?

Comment: There has been one improvement: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_5/MonoTouch_5.2#New_Reference_Counting_System, but it will not cover all cases (in particular it will not cover the sample in my response). Beyond this we will continue to pursue improvements, it is however close to impossible to fix every single case.

Comment: My monotouch is 5.2.5 ... How to enable Mono's SGen Garbage Collector?

Comment: There's a checkbox in the project's options.

Comment: Ok. I have found in IphoneBuild->Advanced and in section Runtime Option there is...;) Thanks a lot...I'll send you a feedback on it!